# Is there a way to install back the original Mono to Raspbian?

Tags: raspbian, mono

I think it was the Mono 3.2.8, but I have installed Mono 5.2.0 and I can't rollback to that version. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: How did you install the new version?

Comment: http://www.mono-project.com/download/#download-lin-raspbian
This way. But also with the .NET and with Mono 5.2.0, my app has problems (something is with the async methods). It worked better in mono 3.2.8, so that's why I want to reinstall that.

Answer (score 1):

Follow steps from Dr. Rabbit, then these: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33763177/install-older-version-of-mono

You make your debian repo point to a snapshot of a release, instead of the current stable release.

Answer (score 0):

Purge all the base libraries and everything dependent will be removed

```
sudo apt-get purge libmono* cli-common mono-runtime
```

then cleanup

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

Comment: That's okay, but how will I reinstall the mono 3.2.8?

Comment: I don't know what exact steps I did. But for sure sudo apt-get purge libmono* cli-common mono-runtime
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get purge mono-devel

in this moment mono --version doesn't respond, what is a good thing. 
after this I removed /etc/apt/sources.list.d/xamarin-list or a file with similar xamarin name. 
After this, I did: 
sudo apt-get install mono-complete
And finally I can see it installs things with version 3.2.8. I will repeat the steps in the near future to test this answer out, and I write my own answer in here.

Comment: so did the answer help you or are you still stuck?

Comment: Yes, your answer helped me, but only partially, because basically you didn't answer to my question. You only wrote about how to delete the mono 5.2, but I needed to find out how to restore mono 3.2.8. But thanks anyway.

Comment: cant you just go to the website and download the package version you require? [link](http://download.mono-project.com/sources/mono/)